# #reduce loop within an #each loop isn't iterating through entire array

Tags: ruby

In the following program, the loop seems to stop after 2 runs, instead of 3 as expected.  The expected value of `sum_of_sums` is 35, but here it is 23.

```
ary = [1,2,3,4]
sum_of_sums = 0
ary.each do  # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
  n=ary.shift  # => 1,         2
  sum_of_products = ary.reduce(0) do |memo,e|  # => [2, 3, 4], [3, 4]
                      memo+(n*e)  # => 2, 5, 9, 6, 14
                    end
  sum_of_sums += sum_of_products  # => 9, 23
end
sum_of_sums  # => 23
```

It works as expected with [1,2,3]:

```
ary = [1,2,3]
sum_of_sums = 0
ary.each do  # => [1, 2, 3]
  n=ary.shift  # => 1,      2
  sum_of_products = ary.reduce(0) do |memo,e|  # => [2, 3], [3]
                      memo+(n*e)  # => 2, 5, 6
                    end
  sum_of_sums += sum_of_products  # => 5, 11
end
sum_of_sums  # => 11
```

I'm trying to write a program which, for a set [a,b,c,d], computes
`ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd`.  I don't know how to express this pattern other than by example.  And yes I could probably do it more explicitly, or more easily by factoring out terms, but I want to know why this loop isn't working!

EDIT: Thanks folks... It seems the problem was that the array was being modified with `#shift` within the `#each` loop.  I ended up succeeding with this:

```
ary = [1,2,3,4]
sum = 0
until ary.count==1 do
  sum += ary.shift * ary.sum
end
sum
```

Comment: Well maybe the function could be verbally expressed as: "The sum of the products of each element multiplied by each of its own successors in the set."  And this might correspond more clearly with `a(b+c+d) + b(c+d) + cd`

Comment: Your code doesn't work as expected because it modifies the array (with `arr.shift`) while iterating the array (`arr.each`).

Comment: A tip on debugging when a program does not work as expected is to always print or `pp` your variables to see what the program is doing. In this case you might have `pp ary` insie your loop and seen that something was wrong and noticed the loop terminates early.

Comment: Normally you would do `ary.each do |n|` ... you don't need to `shift`

Comment: " I don't know how to express this pattern other than by example": Try `ary.combination(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like spickermann said your are modifying the array you are iterating while iterating it. This will produce unexpected results.

If you want to use `shift` then construct the loop using something which is not affected by shifting (modifying) the array.

```
(ary.size-1).times.map { ary.shift * ary.sum }.sum
```

Without modifying the array it becomes a bit more verbose:

```
(ary.size-1).times.map { |i| ary[i] * ary.drop(i+1).sum }.sum
```

You could also make a duplicate before iteration:

```
ary.dup.map { ary.shift * ary.sum }.sum
```

Or using `with_index`:

```
ary.map.with_index { |n, i| n * ary.drop(i+1).sum }.sum
```

There are many other ways to do this too, but hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks! I had a hunch it was related to the `#shift`, but couldn't see it in the return values.  I ended up going with this:
`ary=[1,2,3,4]`
`sum = 0`
`until ary.count==1 do`  
`x = ary.shift`  
`sum += x * ary.sum`  
`end`  
`sum`

sorry, formatting!

Comment: But I still don't understand why the original program worked with [1,2,3] but not [1,2,3,4]

Comment: See here. Maybe this helps to understand what is going on. The code shows what happens when you `shift` while looping different length arrays. https://ideone.com/2uu85l

Comment: `reduce` would work as well `ary.each.with_index(1).reduce(0){|memo,(e,i)| memo +=  e * ary.drop(i).sum}`

Answer (score 2):

Considering that your question has been answered I would like to suggest a more efficient way to perform the calculation. Notice that

```
(a+b+c)**2 = a**2 + b**2 + c**2 + 2*(ab + ac + bc)
```

so

```
ab + ac + bc = ((a+b+c)**2 - (a**2 + b**2 + c**2))/2
```

We therefore may write

```
def sum_of_cross_terms(arr)
  ((arr.sum)**2 - arr.reduce(0) { |t,n| t + n**2 })/2
end
```

```
sum_of_cross_terms([1, 2, 3])
  #=> 11
```

```
sum_of_cross_terms([1, 2, 3, 4])
  #=> 35
```

We see that the computational complexity of this calculation is O(`arr.size`),
whereas the brute-force approach is O(`(arr.size)**2`). An example of the latter is

```
def sum_of_cross_terms(arr)
  arr.combination(2).sum { |a,b| a*b }
end
```